# Skill closing and google opens recipe

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

We are developing interactive audiobooks for voice and have problems with some of our continuations with google assistant.

Example: In our story "Das tapfere Schneiderlein", the user hast to decide if he wants "Pflaumenmus" (plum butter) or "Apfelmus" (apple puree).

1. In the Test-console, everything works fine, both answers lead to the correct audio.
2. BUT with Google Assistant on Mobile device, only Pflaumenmus works. If I answer "Apfelmus", the action leaves conversations and opens Apple puree recipes with Google search. (see example image below, it's German, but still understandable I guess)

As we can never now, what our customers might answer, how can we prevent this from happening? (We are using Actions Builder.)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bXle.png)

Comment: You say you're using the "Conversational Actions SDK". To be clear, are you doing that with the [Actions Builder](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview), [Dialogflow](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/overview), or the [Legacy Actions SDK with your own NLU](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/overview)?

Comment: Thanx for asking: We use Actions Builder.

Comment: It will help if you update your question to include screen shots of the Scene where this is happening, along with screen shots of any Intents and Types that you may be using. The more details about why you think it should be capturing "Apfelmus", the better our chances are of being able to help. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a result of an update regarding the Google Assistant Actions fallback intent behavior change that we announced on October 15/2020.

Follow the message from Google to make it work as you expect:

> In order to provide a better experience, we now allow users to ask for some Assistant features, such as the weather or time, from within your Action. To perform this function, the Assistant detects if your Action matched a user's query with a fallback intent or NO_MATCH intent. If that is the case, and an appropriate response is available, Assistant responds to the user's request. If no response is available, or Assistant doesn't understand the query, the conversation continues within your Action.
>
> As of October 15, 2020, this new behavior applies only if the fallback does not use a webhook. Starting January 15th 2021, we'll start enabling this feature for any Dialogflow fallback intent or Actions Builder NO_MATCH intent whether or not they use a webhook.
>
> This change should not impact the operation of your Actions, unless you are using fallbacks as a way to collect input from your users. Going forward, you should only use fallback intents or NO_MATCH intents as a way to reprompt the user in the context of your Action. If you want your Actions to attempt to capture data from a wider range of user responses, create an intent that uses a Free form text type if you use Actions Builder. If you use Dialogflow, add an intent with a @sys.any type as the training phrase.

Comment: We use NO_MATCH, but: our response (before the error) sets a dedicated slot in a scene, and the slot values contain "apfelmus". So the NO_MATCH intent shouldn't even be triggered in the first place - and it isn't triggered from the actions console. Only from the assistant. That's why it is so hard to debug.

Comment: Yes! That´s the behavior... My advice is to create an Type of "Free form text" kind, for example "UnhandledType" and then create an intent as "UnhandledIntent" with a single training phrase "unhandled" pointing to an parameter and apply the "UnhandledType" as Data type. 
Then you can use this "UnhandledIntent" in your scene and point to you webhook or even respond accordingly on the occurrence of an unknown term user query.

Comment: NO_MATCH definitely is not been working as expected after this update. I struggled for many days with that till get this solution!

Comment: OK thanks very much! We'll try the UnhandledType approach.